Utilizing non-recommended digital I/O pins on the Wemos D1 Mini
I need to connect to a Wemos D1 Mini (ESP8266) the following components:

SD card
RTC
2x DS18B20 temperature sensors

The SD card and RTC are mounted on a shield and I cannot change the pins assigned to them (D5, D6, D7, D8 for the SD card and D1, D2 for the RTC).
I am running out of digital pins on the device. Infact, the only available pins left on the device are:

RX and TX (PIN 21 and 22)
D3 and D4

However, all those pins produce some issues when used as an input:

RX and TX: boot fails if pulled LOW
D3 and D4: boot fails if pulled LOW

Since the device won't boot with the temperature sensors connected to those pins, what are my options?

DS18B20 uses 1-wire which requires an external pull-up resistor, and as such should never be pulled low at boot. So connecting to Tx/Rx/D3/D4 shouldn't have any impact. Have you tried connecting them to these pins yet?

I forgot to add the pull-up resistor. Thank you very much :)

The DS18B20 uses 1-wire interface which idles high when not in use. This should therefore be compatible with the pins which have to be high during boot. That allows you to in theory use any of the four stated digital pins.
1-wire does however require a relatively low value external pull-up resistor (4.7kΩ). If this is not present, then the loading from the devices trying to draw parasitic power from these lines may be overwhelming any internal pull-ups on the ESP8266 which would explain why you are getting boot issues.
Adding an external pull-up should fix this issue.
